# Unexpected result when Lotus Notes agent is ran on the server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotus Notes agent that search a database then return the result in Excel format. I got the correct result when I run the Agent using Trigger: On Event -> Action menu selection. But when I schedule to run the agent on the server, I received a different result. There are always 10 documents that keeps showing up on the first 10 rows of the Excel file and I cannot find those 10 documents in the database when I search for them manually in the database.

A few things that are different about the agent that I ran from my PC and from the server:

1. I have Office 2010 and the server has Office 2003, so the SaveAs method use different parameter

   ```
   xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs file_Path, 43 'for Office 2003

   xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs file_Path, 56 'for Office 2010
   ```
2. Running the agent from my PC saves the Excel file in my local hard drive. Running the agent from the server saves the Excel file on the path below:

   ```
   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop\FileName.xls
   ```

My search statement:

```
search_Formula = {Form = "WORec" & SoftDelete != "Y" & WO_Dept="REPAIR" & } & _ 
    {WO_Status != "Completed" & WO_Status != "Declined" & } & _
    {@Like(WOBinNumber; "R%")}
```

I do not think any of those two differences cause the problem, but I do not know what else to try since I cannot step through the code when it is running on the server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: >  since I cannot step through the code when it is running on the server - actually, you can. Look into designer help, remote debugger or google for rdebug task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run an agent manually, you run it under the security context of the current user.  A scheduled agent runs under the security context of the server.

If there are documents that have reader fields on them, they may only be visible to certain users (i.e. the server, and not you).

You may be able to see these documents if you go to the server and launch Notes on the server itself.

Comment: On the server do I launch Notes with my Notes id or the server id? I opened the database on my PC using the server.id but could not find the documents that showed up on the Excel file

Comment: When you used the server.id on your own PC, did you open a local replica of the database?  If so, then that replica was created with your ID, so it would only contain the documents that your ID can access.  If you actually managed to open it on the server, well... I'm surprised, because I thought the server security would reject remote connections from another device using it's own ID.  (But I could be wrong about that.)  Anyhow, I would suggest another test.  Assuming you have the rights, or can get them, open the database on the server using an ID with "Full Access Administration" rights.

Comment: well well, apparently I can see those documents using "Full Access Administration" rights using my Notes id. Really odd, but I get the answer. Thanks Ken and Richard!